# Does the Amazon SP API CreateFeedDocument accept json as the contentType for the POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS feed?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

The [documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feed-type-values#:%7E:text=FBA%20Inbound%20Shipment%20Carton%20Information%20Feed) provides the .xsd file for the request format. I want to know if I can use json instead of xml.
I cannot test this at the moment because the sandbox only supports testing the
`POST_PRODUCT_DATA`
feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not according to the documentation, at the moment of writing. The [Feeds API Use Case Guide](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feeds-api-v2021-06-30-use-case-guide) clearly states which documents can be formatted as JSON, and which as XML, and which as flat file (CSV).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can only use JSON schemas for the feeds listed on [this](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/feed-json-schemas) page.